# communication between a parent process and a child process

Tags: java, multithreading, parent-child, child-process

I have a class that acts as a parent process. During its run, it creates many child process and runs them simultaneously. Each child process is basically an HTTP client that connects to a service and pulls data from it.

Currently, if one of the child processes stop working from any reason, the parent process re-establishing the connection by restarting that same child process.

The disconnection of the child process may be caused by several thing. I would like to communicate the reason for disconnection from the child process to the parent process and have the parent process act accordingly based on the reason of disconnection (socket read fail, 404 not found, 401 unauthorized etc.).

Is it possible? What would be the shortest/best way to do it?
Here is my Parent class:

```
public class Parent {
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Process> PRlist = new ArrayList<Process>();
    List<String[]> commandsList = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    DateTimeFormatter frmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm:ss");

    if (args.length == 2 && args[0].matches("-f")){
        String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        String path = dir + "/" + args[1];
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
            BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);

            String line = "";
            while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null){
                String[] tk = line.split(" ");
                String[] cmd = {"java", "-jar", "Child.jar", "-a", tk[0], "-p", tk[1],
                        "-u", tk[2], "-pw", tk[3], "-m", tk[4], "-s", tk[5]};
                Process pr = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(cmd).redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT).start();
                PRlist.add(pr); commandsList.add(cmd);
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();} 
        catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}

        int streamnum = PRlist.size();

        while (true){
            for (int i = 0; i < streamnum; i++){
                if (!PRlist.get(i).isAlive()){
                    PRlist.get(i).destroy();
                    PRlist.remove(i);
                    try {
                        Process PR = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(commandsList.get(i)).redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT).start();
                        System.out.println(commandsList.get(i)[12] + " stream re-established at " + LocalDateTime.now().format(frmt));
                        PRlist.add(i,PR);
                    } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
                }
            }

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("No stream file was specified.");
    }
}}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any reason why you use separate JVM instances instead of Java threads? It would be more memory-efficient and far easier to solve your problem.

Comment: +1 to @BorisShchegolev.  Unless you have some very interesting reasoning you really should be doing this with an ExecutorService and collecting the information you need via a Future.

Comment: @BorisShchegolev I just wrote it like this from the beginning, no special reason. If i will change the processes o threads, how would you recommend solving my issue? any examples?

Comment: Don't know much about `ExecutorService` and `Future`. Care to elaborate? Any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As example

Someting like

```
if (!PRlist.get(i).isAlive()){
    int exitCode=PRlist.get(i).exitValue();
    //Do something with exitValue

    PRlist.get(i).destroy();
    PRlist.get(i).destroy();
    PRlist.remove(i);
    try {
        Process PR = new ProcessBuilder().inheritIO().command(commandsList.get(i)).redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT).start();
        System.out.println(commandsList.get(i)[12] + " stream re-established at " + LocalDateTime.now().format(frmt));
         PRlist.add(i,PR);
         } catch (IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
         }
```

Examples with errorStream may be more complex, but the idea is looking at the exception being posted in errorStream via text processing.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this approach.

Comment: That idea works fine for me. Thank you. Still going to try the approach presented by @BorisShchegolev to see if it will save me some memory.

Comment: You're welcome. 
I think anyway that the Threads approach gives you more control over your subprocesses. I don't know about memory, because opening a lot of Threads may be resource consuming anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with the methods

```
**public ProcessBuilder.Redirect redirectError()**
Returns this process builder's standard error destination. Subprocesses   subsequently started by this object's start() method redirect their standard error to this destination. The initial value is Redirect.PIPE.
Returns:
this process builder's standard error destination
```

Or

```
public abstract int exitValue()
Returns the exit value for the subprocess.
Returns:
the exit value of the subprocess represented by this Process object. By convention, the value 0 indicates normal termination.
Throws:
IllegalThreadStateException - if the subprocess represented by this Process object has not yet terminated
```

Comment: Can you provide some short example to for your idea?

Comment: FOr example something like

Comment: What is it? I think something is missing in your comment.

Comment: it was saved as it is (erroneus enter :) ..), i posted a new answer

Answer (score 0):

OK, with Java Threads you would do it like this:

```
class MyThreadedApp {

    // main() here

    /**
     * Starting a new thread
     */
    private void start() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                new Worker().run();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                threadEnded(ex);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    /**
     * Handle errors
     * 
     * @param ex Error
     */
    private void threadEnded(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

/**
 * My worker thread
 */
class Worker {

    void run() throws IOException {
        // Do my stuff here
    }
}
```

That's a basic example just to demonstrate the data flow. In practice you could have some use of technologies @lscoughlin mentioned.

Comment: Thank you. I see that you are trying to catch an exception when `Worker().run` in order to utilize the error to do something. Will the same concept will work if there are no error being thrown? for example, server replied 404 and no error was thrown, thread only stopped working.

Comment: For any other condition then `HTTP 20x` your worker thread should throw an exception. It's usually pretty easy to achieve.